# How to automate an Excel document and work on other excel document at the same time?

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-automation

I'm using a program to automate an excel document and in the meantime I would like to open others Excel documents and work on these (not automated).

When I open an document while my automation is running, the file I open is frozed and I can't access to it. I tried to set the visible property of my automation program to false, but if I modify an document it creates an exception.

Is it possible to automate an excel document and open and work others excel document at the same time?

Thank you in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Do you open new documents via the File > Open? If so then the new documents are opened in the same Excel process. This causes freezes if one of the documents is doing intensive calculations.

Solution to this is to open documents in new Excel process. You can do this by opening a new Excel window and go to File > Open from there. If you have one Excel window opened and you open a document it will also start in the existing Excel process. You can check how many Excels you have opened in your Task manager.

Some more information can be found [here](http://blog.thomascsherman.com/2010/06/opening-excel-files-in-new-processes-excel-launcher-helper-app/) and [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/491926-opening-entirely-new-process-instance-excel.html).

Comment: Your solution has been helpful! Thank you! As you said I open a new excel process and open an excel document with this new process so I can automate an excel document and open another one.